# Avoiding hardcode solution to post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this post method

```
$.post("/abc/export.action",
              { 
                sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
                exportType: "xls",
                param1:compareData,
                param2:comparePatchData},
                  function(resdata)
                  {
                        alert(resdata);
                  }
            );
```

I wanted some best practice so that I can have enumeration or array which stores all my post parameters in it and use it while post, A way in which I can avoid hardcoding of `sessiontoken`, `param1` etc.. what could be the solution?

**EDIT**

Sometimes it might happen that I need to change the names of `params` so i have to edit everywhere I have `post` method, instead of that if all the params where there in some enum or array it would be much easier to just change at one place.

Comment: If you have an object containing all data to send, why don't you use the object as the second parameter of `$.post()`? `$.post('/abc/export.action', dataobj, function (resdata) { alert(resdata); });` I'm afraid I don't completely understand what's your problem.

Comment: @duri: I edited my question to explain more

Comment: @Abhishek - if you want to use the same parameters in all (or most) cases of `$.post()` just do what duri said, or see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the labels in a object to be based on some other variable you can do it with

```
  var paramLabels = {"session": "sessionToken", "type": "exportType", ...}
  var paramValues = {}; 
  paramValues[paramLabels.session] =  sessionToken; 
  paramValues[paramLabels.type] = "xls"
  ...

  $.post(/"abc/export.action", paramValues, function(resdata) { alert(resdata);});
```

I can't really see the benefit of this approach expect when the developers of the backend like to change the names of the parameters every five minutes.

Another way of handling this would be to create a factory method or a builder

```
  function createParams(session, type, ...) {
     return { "sessionToken": session, "exportType": type, ...) }
  }

  var params = createParams(sessionToken, "xls", ...);
```

or

```
  var Parameters = function() {  
      this.session = function(session) { this.session = session; return this;}
      this.type = function(type) { this.type = type; return this;} 
      ...
      this.build = function() {     
            var params = {}
            !this.session || params.sessionToken = this.session;
            !this.type || params.exportType = this.type;
            ...
            return params;

      }
  } 

   var params = new Parameters().session(sessionToken).type("xls")...build();
```

Both of these approaches let you define the concreate name of the parameters only once. The latter may be easier to reuse when different set of parameters are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing an object literal to `$.post()` you can pass an object that was defined elsewhere in your code, and thus re-use that same object for multiple posts. Or put in a function call that returns an object with the appropriate parameters set up.

```
var postParams = {
  sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
  exportType: "xls",
  param1:compareData,
  param2:comparePatchData
};

$.post("/abc/export.action",
       postParams,
       function(resdata) { alert(resdata); });

$.post("/abc/import.action",
       postParams,
       function(resdata) { alert(resdata); });

// or use a function that can return a different object
// depending on some conditions (or parameters passed to
// the function though I haven't shown that)
function getPostParams() {
  if (someCondition)
    return postParams;
  else
    return {
      sessionToken : something,
      // etc.
    };
}

$.post("/abc/someother.action",
       getPostParams(),
       function(resdata) { alert(resdata); });
```